# Как добавлять шаблоны html с измененным текстом через админ-панель в WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, реализация

Есть верстка одной страницы, в этой верстке есть слайдер с отзывами от пользователей и пользователи соответственно могут оставлять новые отзывы. Это происходит таким образом, пользователь пишет отзыв в форме где заполняет два поля: ФИО, Отзыв. После отправки формы данные с полей отправляются на почту, этот отзыв смотрят и решают добавить его в этот слайдер или нет. И вот с добавлением его в слайдер и возникают "непонятки". Можно конечно копировать текст отзыва с письма и прямо в файле `.php` написать еще один блок слайдера, но уже с соответствующим текстом, но думаю есть и другой выход. В самом WordPress я не силен, но почти уверен, что есть такой метод чтобы написать текст отзыва в админ-панели и он сам вставит этот текст в соответствующий `html` шаблон и добавить в нужное место на странице.
Т.е. в моем скудном представлении это выглядит следующим образом:
Я пишу `html` шаблон, в моем представлении выглядит примерно так:

```html
<div class="review">

    <div class="reivew-title>
        <div class="review-title-photo"></div>
        <div class="review-title-name"><?php esc_html($review_name); ?></div>
    </div>

    <div class="review-content">
        <div class="review-content-text">
            <?php esc_html($review_content_text); ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Потом в админ-панели пишу значения переменных `$review_name` и `$review_content_text` и они подставляются на нужное в написанном шаблоне и этот шаблон вставляется в нужное место на странице.
И вот, как можно сделать вышеописанное и есть ли такое вообще? Или для этого другой выход, если да, то какой?
*P.S. Я много гуглил и лишь примерно понимаю, что можно использовать шорткоды, но как использовать тоже не очень понятно*
*P.S. Использование плагинов привествуется*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавляем шорткод через ф-цию `add_shortcode`, вторым параметром указываем callback ф-цию `my_review_function`:

```
add_shortcode( 'review', 'my_review_function', );
function my_review_function( $atts ) {
    if ( empty( $atts['name'] || empty( $atts['content'] ) ) {
        return;
    }
    ?>
    <div class="review">
         <div class="reivew-title>
             <div class="review-title-photo"></div>
             <div class="review-title-name"><?php echo esc_html($atts['name'] ); ?>
         </div>
    </div>

        <div class="review-content">
            <div class="review-content-text">
                <?php echo esc_html($atts['content'] ); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Аттрибуты `$atts` - это массив аттрибуттов шорткода в виде key=value.

Пример использования: `[review name='Some name' content='Content']`

Comment: хм, думаю то что нужно, вы можете как то раскрыть свой ответ пожалуйста?

Comment: сейчас сделаю))

Comment: Галочкой отметьте ответ принятым

Comment: пожалуйста, раскройте ответ по шире, вы многим поможете своим ответом, я уверен)